# Что происходит когда добавляешь разметку в функцию?

Tags: php

Вот пример кода:

```
<?php
function func()
{

?>
<p>paragraph</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Вот скажите мне в чём смысл вопроса? Попробовать запустить скрипт никак?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Та ничего не должно произойти. `<p>paragraph</p>` появится на странице при выполнении func().

Comment: Это я знаю. Я хотел бы понять логику что с этим делает интерпретатор.

Comment: Интерпретатор видит открывающий тег php, выполняет код - ищет закрывающий, этот код выполняется и преобразуется в текст / html на выходе. Если нет вставок php, то просто читается содержимое файла как текст / html и выводится.

Грубо и поверхностно, но так. =)